# how use datareader while getting a value to the textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqldatareader

Hey Friend i am using a form with a **combobox**in which the items i have taken from the 
sqldatabase named as balance and that sqldatabase have two columns one is customername and the 
another is obbalance now .

In the form i had binded all the customer names from the table and now i have a textbox i want to do is 
when the user selects the combobox.selected item any one customer name i need to display the obbalance of the selected customer in tat textbox

Ihad used the datareader but it shows error can you plz help me........

```
    Dim ST As String = ComboBox1.SelectedItem

    Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection(conectionstring)

    Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT OBBALANCE FROM BALANCE WHERE CUSTOMERNAME =  " & " '" & ST & "'" & "", sqlcon)
    Dim sdr As New SqlDataReader


    Try
        con.Open()
        sdr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader
        While (sdr.Read())
            Textbox7.Text = sdr[1]

        End While
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
```

Icant understand how to read plz help me to read the data and in the table first is column name and next is obbalance field

Answer (score 3):

Since you are going read a single value from the database, use **[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)** method instead of using a datareader.

```
Dim ST As String = ComboBox1.SelectedText 

Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection(conectionstring)

Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT OBBALANCE FROM BALANCE WHERE CUSTOMERNAME = '" & ST & "'" , sqlcon)
Dim result as Object

Try
    con.Open()

    result = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar()

    If result IsNot Nothing Then
         Textbox7.Text = result.ToString() 
    End If

Catch ex As SqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)     

End Try
```

**Update:**
Modified the code to check for null.
Removed the datareader object as it is no longer required.
Removed unnecessary characters from query.

Comment: hey it saysObject reference not set to an instance of an object. on the 2nd line of try block

Comment: That will happen if your query returns an empty resultset. i have updated the code to add null checking. Execute the query in SQL Server management studio and make sure you are getting the output.

Comment: sir now it show error in Error 1 Type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' has no constructors. C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\SHOPPROJECT\SHOPPROJECT\Form1.vb 23 17 SHOPPROJECT
In the fourth line it sayin no constructor now what can i do ...

Comment: Sir i had seen by executing step by step i noticed that it always saying for all customername i am selecting its nothing but u knw i had get the data form that table only in that table both the column have the data den wat problem does my sqlcommand is correct only na selected obbalance from balance whose customername is comboboxselected item

Comment: I have removed the datareader object, I had copy pasted it from your original listing by mistake. it is not required.

Comment: I am not sure why your query is not returning null, did you try copying the query while you are debugging and executing it from SQL server directly? Also check your connection string to make sure you are connecting to the correct database

Comment: I don't think selecting the customer by name is a good idea. If this is a production system, then you definitely need to use the customer id (or whatever primary key you have on the table) for the where criteria. if you have 2 customers with the same name, your current logic will fail.

Comment: Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection(conectionstring) check this line
and this line con.Open()
trying to open another connection?

Comment: ya i have two connection string in tat form one for con and another as sqlcom does this affects it

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ST As String = ComboBox1.SelectedText 

    Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection(conectionstring)

    Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT OBBALANCE FROM BALANCE WHERE CUSTOMERNAME =  " & " '" & ST & "'" & "", sqlcon)
  Dim sdr As SqlDataReader


    Try
        sqlcon.Open() 'edited
        sdr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
        While (sdr.Read())
            TextBox1.Text = sdr("OBBALANCE").ToString() 'sdr(1) is wrong since there is only one item
        End While
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)


    End Try
```

Comment: Textbox7.Text = sdr["OBBALANCE"].ToString()

Comment: Error 1 Value of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' cannot be converted to 'String'. C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\SHOPPROJECT\SHOPPROJECT\SALE.vb 142 29 SHOPPROJECT

Comment: Error 2 Identifier expected. C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\SHOPPROJECT\SHOPPROJECT\SALE.vb 142 33 SHOPPROJECT

Comment: ya now it run but the textbox still not contain the value y.?

Comment: is there any value in table ? check the query

Comment: i check edited still it does not show anything in tat textbox it fully nothing